# Edit word with php

Tags: php

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

$archivo = 'Document.docx'; // Ruta al archivo de Word


$palabraAntigua = 'name';
$nuevaPalabra = 'Manolooo';


$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($archivo);


$templateProcessor->setValue($palabraAntigua, $nuevaPalabra);


$archivoModificado = 'Document2.docx'; // Ruta al nuevo archivo de Word
$templateProcessor->saveAs($archivoModificado);

echo "La palabra '$palabraAntigua' ha sido reemplazada por '$nuevaPalabra' y se ha guardado en el archivo '$archivoModificado'.";
```

With this code it does not change the word, it creates the new file but with the same as the original, without any change:

Comment: *setValue()* is for filling *variables* in the template document. Variables have this format: `${name}`

Comment: nobody knowss??